# java notifyAll: illegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to simulate that a mother call three child to eat dinner, here is my code:

```
class child extends Thread{
    String name;
    mother mom;
    public child(mother mon, String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.mom = mom;
    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println(name+" is hungry.");
        while (!mom.finished){
            try {
                wait();
            }catch(InterruptedException e){}
        }
        washhands();
    }

    public synchronized void washhands(){
        System.out.println(name+" washed hands.");
        notifyAll();
    }
}

class mother{
    boolean finished;

    public mother(){
        finished = false;
    }
    public void cook(){
        System.out.println("Mom started cooking.");
        try{
            Thread.sleep(200);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){};
        finished = true;
        System.out.println("Mom finished cooking.");
        notifyAll();
    }
}

public class work{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        mother mom = new mother();
        child Alex = new child(mom, "Alex");
        child James = new child(mom, "James");
        child Tod = new child(mom, "Tod");

        Alex.start();
        James.start();
        Tod.start();
        mom.cook();
    }
}
```

So I got a "exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException" at the line of notifyAll() in class mother. I don't know what happens, some one can help me?

Comment: wait and notify can only be called in a guarded block, take a look at this link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: Are you required to use wait and notifyAll directly? If not, I suggest `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore".

Comment: you need to capture child objects in Mom class and then notify them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider following points.

1. You have to use a common object to guard all the blocks of code which required mutual exclusion.
2. wait/notify can only be called on an object if it's monitor is locked by current thread.
3. To acquire a monitor a thread has to enter a block which is guarded by object which owns the monitor. Monitors are internally used by JVM.

Apart from it name your classes and variables using [Java naming conventions.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

See the code below

```
synchronized void method1 () {
}

synchronized void method2() {
}
```

Here `method1` and `method2` will be guarded by the monitor of object on which these will be called. So if we want to use the same monitor inside a guarded block it will be done as below.

```
public void method3() {
    synchronized(this) {
    }
    ...
}
```

Now `method1()`, `method2()` and guarded block in `method3()` will be protected by same object monitor.

If we need guarded blocks across classes then we need to share a common object among them. I have made the same modification in your code below.

```
package filevisitor;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

class child extends Thread{
    String name;
    volatile mother mom;
    public child(mother mom, String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.mom = mom;
    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println(name+" is hungry.");
        while (!mom.finished){
            try {
                synchronized(work.myLockObject) {
                    work.myLockObject.wait();
                }
            }catch(InterruptedException e){}
        }
        washhands();
    }

    public void washhands(){
        System.out.println(name+" washed hands.");
        synchronized(work.myLockObject) {
            work.myLockObject.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}

class mother{
    boolean finished;

    public mother(){
        finished = false;
    }
    public void cook(){
        System.out.println("Mom started cooking.");
        try{
            Thread.sleep(200);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){};
        finished = true;
        System.out.println("Mom finished cooking.");
        synchronized(work.myLockObject) {
            work.myLockObject.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}

public class work{
    public static final Object myLockObject = new Object();
    public static void main(String[] args){
        mother mom = new mother();
        child Alex = new child(mom, "Alex");
        child James = new child(mom, "James");
        child Tod = new child(mom, "Tod");

        Alex.start();
        James.start();
        Tod.start();
        mom.cook();
    }
}
```

Also there was a minor mistake at `this.mom = mom;` in child class. Parameter name is `mon` so this assignment was doing nothing resulting in `NullPointerException`.

**Output**

```
Mom started cooking.
Alex is hungry.
Tod is hungry.
James is hungry.
Mom finished cooking.
Tod washed hands.
James washed hands.
Alex washed hands.
```

Answer (score 0):

As you need to notify children once mom is finished with cooking. Right now you are calling notifyAll() on mom object itself which does not look functionally correct. One way is to pass child object reference to Mom and notify them once Mom is finished with cooking